# Spring Framework: Is there a list of "reserved words" or "Predefined Variables" about SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-el

For `Spring Framework` where is the complete list of *reserved words* or *Predefined Variables* about `SpEL` with their respective explanation? It such as for:

- `environment`
- `systemProperties`
- `systemEnvironment`

For example in this valuable tutorial is just shown the 2 latest of the list shown above

- [Spring Expression Language (SpEL) Predefined Variables](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-expression-language)

Consider if Spring 6 added more of them, it as an improvement, therefore could be more.

Yes, I did do a research - currently for version 6 - at the official documentation at:

- [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions)

But does not contain the reserved words.

**Note:**

Yes, appears the `getSystemEnvironment()` and `getSystemProperties()` methods at the [AbstractEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html) class, but see the following class:

- [StandardEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) - subclass of `AbstractEnvironment`

See the `Field Summary` section, it has the `systemEnvironment` and `systemProperties` variables used by SpEL. I am assuming other class would have the `enviroment` variable

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [expressions-beandef](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-beandef)

Comment: There, appear 2 of 3, same as [StandardEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) . wondered why does not appear `system`, it is used to retrieve the values of a `.properties` file through the `@Value` and `@PropertySource`

Comment: btw, is **not** `system` - it does not exist - it is `environment`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a list of reserved words for SpEL like what you are looking for, at least not in generic SpEL parsing and evaluation.

There is default SpEL support *in the application context* and notably in `@Value` annotations, as documented in the reference guide: [Expressions in Bean Definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-beandef).

Thi is provided via a SpEL `StandardEvaluationContext` which uses the `beanFactory` as the root object. Or rather, it uses a `BeanExpressionContext` view of the bean factory plus a dedicated `PropertyAccessor` is added to this evaluation context so that every `beanName` in the bean factory is considered a *property* of that root object during evaluation.

As a result, if a bean named `foo` is registered in the factory, `@Value("#{ foo }")` will be interpreted as "the property `foo` of the root object", which resolves to the aforementioned bean.

So `systemProperties`/`systemEnvironment` and `environment` are not really predefined `SpEL` variables, but rather standard beans in an `AbstractApplicationContext`.

Comment: About your latest paragraph, see the _Note_ section added in my post